# AspNetCore SignalR Аутентификация на клиентах

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Здравствуйте имеется сервер AspNetCore SignalR, на сервере открыты 2 хаба.
к 1 хабу подключается С# клиент из (WinForms приложения)
к 2 хабу подключается Js клиент со странички браузера.

Хотелось бы иметь список клиентов подключенных к каждому хабу.
Информацию о клиенте можно брать из контекста подключения Context.User
Но как добавлять информацию об Аутентификации на клиенте?

СЕРВЕР:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public ChatHub() 
    {
        _communicateHubs = communicateHubs;
    }


    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var ip = Context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        var ip = Context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

КЛИЕНТ1 (С#)

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("http://localhost:9725/Hub1")
    .Build();   
await connection.StartAsync();  
//Где в HubConnectionBuilder настроить User клиента?
```

КЛИЕНТ2 (JS)

```
<script>
    let hubUrl = 'http://localhost:9725/webui';
    let httpConnection = new signalR.HttpConnection(hubUrl);
    let hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnection(httpConnection);

    hubConnection.on("Send", function (data) {
        let elem = document.createElement("p");
        elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
        let firstElem = document.getElementById("chatroom").firstChild;
        document.getElementById("chatroom").insertBefore(elem, firstElem);
    });
         
    document.getElementById("sendBtn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        let message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        hubConnection.invoke("Send", message);
    });
 
    hubConnection.start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятен вопрос, но возможно это поможет: Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated передавать на клиент сразу после установки соединения

Comment: Я имел ввиду, как клиенту задать свое имя например "Pety". И после выполнения await connection.StartAsync();  сервер знал что к нему пришел  "Pety". Я передаю имя в header запроса сейчас. и на сервере извлекаю из httpContext.Headers["UserName"].

Comment: Сразу после установления соединения вызвать на сервере метод SetName и передать туда имя:   connection.StartAsync().ContinueWith(r => connection.InvokeAsync("SetName", name).Wait())

Comment: Можно и так, просто хотелось все отрабатывать в универсальном методе сервера OnConnectedAsync(). Чтобы не зависимо от того вызвал ли клиент этот метод знать что он подключился. То как предлагаете вы это еще один уровень "рукопожатия". Я сейчас авторизую клиентов через JWT, вот после авторизации Connect() и еще 1 уровень рукопожатия (то есть еще 1 уровень правил, которые должен выполнить клиент).

Comment: В JWT должно содержаться имя пользователя, я бы на вашем месте посмотрел, как достать имя из JWT.

Comment: Вот ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150223/parsing-jwt-to-get-claims-in-c-sharp

Comment: Спасибо, гляну.